# Laravel - Do something every time Laravel runs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a situation where i have different domains having the A record for my server. So all the domains are pointing to the same laravel server. Now when ever laravel runs i want to get the domain name that sent the request and then change the logo of the website. What is most efficient way of doing this?

I want to keep it light and simple. I just have a few domains so i dont have any issues hardcoding them up to save a db query.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code in your BaseController.php and pass some value to your view to show right logo.

For getting domain name you can simple use Laravel method

```
if (strpos(Request::root(), 'domain1.com') !== false) {
    $domain = 1;
} else if (strpos(Request::root(), 'domain2.com') !== false) {
    $domain = 2;
} else {
    $domain = 3;
}
```

And as I mentioned above, you can share $domain with your view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i also had something similar in mind. I ended up creating a group route middleware and assigning the logo image (link) to the session. Will it have any issues when scaling the server horizontally?

Comment: `Will it have any issues when scaling the server horizontally?` You have to edit the code again for new domain if you use this approach.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, what i mean is if i was using something like aws beanstalk with autoscaling, does the session maintain itself over all the new servers added automatically?